# Javafx Combobox CSS Padding

Tags: css, javafx, javafx-css

I´d like to reduce the padding to show my full text.

I have tried it, but doenst work.

```
.combo-box
{
    -fx-background-color: -color-gray;
    -fx-text-fill: -color-primary;
    -fx-cell-size: 2.5em; 
    -fx-font-family: 'Myriad Pro Light';
    -fx-font-size: 14pt;
    -fx-padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your padding is all 0's, you need to change those values.

Comment: @TGarrett, tried also a value like 2 2 2 2, nothiing too.

Comment: A whole example would be reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and works for me. I don't think padding might be useful for you. Instead, you can change the font-size. If you use a small font-size you should see your text inside that button.

In this type of scenarios, you can use [Scenic View](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/) to view graphics elements and see what the problem might be.

Hope it helps

Comment: thx for trying it out. But I dont like to use a small font-size, it will not look good, I want to figure out how to change the padding of the label box.

Comment: I don't think changing padding could be a solution, as i said before. Maybe you have to use a greater width for the combobox if you don't want to change the font-size

Answer (score 0):

I had to setup negative padding in `.box`:

```
.combo-box
{
    -fx-background-color: -color-gray;
    -fx-text-fill: -color-primary;
    -fx-cell-size: 2.5em; 
    -fx-font-family: 'Myriad Pro Light';
    -fx-font-size: 14pt;
    -fx-padding: -5 -5 -5 -15;
}
```

Also need to remove the padding from default modena.css inside `.arrow-button`

```
.combo-box-base > .arrow-button {
    -fx-background-radius: 0 3 3 0, 0 2 2 0, 0 1 1 0;
    -fx-padding: 0 0.833333em 0 0;
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-alignment:center-left;
}
```